# Proof of a step of a lemma on the asymptotics of maximum likelihood where a Taylor expansion is used. (crosspost from crossvalidated).

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I have asked this question on crossvalidated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152205/proof-of-a-step-of-a-lemma-on-the-asymptotics-of-maximum-likelihood-where-a-tayl) and I am still unsure on the answer. I attempt a cross-post (most of the times this proves very useful).

I copy the question below:

I am trying to understand a proof of quite a long theorem that I report completely for the sake of completeness. 
This is From Jensen and Rahbek *Asymptotic Inference for Nonstationary GARCH* (2004).
My question is actually basic and only regards the Taylor expansion done in the proof so one can skip to the end if he wishes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

At the start of the proof through the mean value theorem $\lambda^*$ is proven to exist. Then a Taylor expansion is made.

$$\Big| \frac{\partial f(\lambda^*)}{\partial \lambda} \Big| = \Big| \sum_{i,j,l = 1}^k v_{1,i}v_{2,j} (\varphi_l - \varphi_{0,l}) \partial^3 \ell_T (\varphi_0 - \lambda^* (\varphi - \varphi_0))/ \partial \varphi_i \varphi_j \varphi_l  \Big|$$

On crossvalidated an answer states that: "It is the Lagrange form of Taylor's theorem with remainder (https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/taylors_thm/) I believe. 
And it is an expansion of f(1) around f(0), ie $f(1)=f(0)+f'(\lambda^*).(1-0)$, for some $\lambda^*\in (0,1)$."

Still I don't understand where does $f(0) = v_2' [D^2 \ell_T( \varphi_0) ] v_2$ go? And why if we are deriving w.r.t. $\lambda$ is the third derivative w.r.t $\varphi$?

(I hope it is ok to quote an other user to whom I am grateful for his attempt to help me).